# How do I put a like button on my page?

Tags: facebook-like

I have just created a simple page for local classifieds in my area.  I simply want to put a like button on the page.  I read the instructions and got the code but I am confused as what exactly to do with the code.  It gives me a large code on the top and a smaller one on the bottom.  Where do I put these codes?  When I go to my main page I dont see a place to add them. I am very new at this and am quite lost on how to do this?  Can anybody explain this simply to me?

Answer (score 0):

Check the official facebook developers guide: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

You can embed that javascript into your page.

Comment: thank you for responding. When you say I can embed that javascriptinto my page....how exactly do I do that?  I dont mean to sound stupid, but where exactly do I place the script?  When I look at my page I just see the wall and normal things...how do you get into the page to place the code?